# How display image during pdf generation using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, wicked-pdf

i am using wicked_pdf and generating pdf of users records.image tag is not working when pdf is generate.So i use this trick and write this code in application helper.

```
     def pdf_image_tag(image, options = {})
       options[:src] = File.expand_path(Rails.root) + '/public' + image
       tag(:img, options)
     end
```

and in my view i call like this

```
      <%= pdf_image_tag(@image.snap.url(:thumb)) unless @image.blank? %>
```

This is working fine for chrome and display image perfectly but not for other browsers.

Can any one give better suggestion.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in helper `wicked_pdf_image_tag`

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag(@image.snap.url(:thumb)) unless @image.blank? %>
```

Comment: when i use <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag(@image.snap.url(:thumb)) unless @image.blank? %>  i have this error.        ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pathname' for nil:NilClass): on my local envirnoment but in case of this code         <%= pdf_image_tag(@image.snap.url(:thumb)) unless @image.blank? %> display image properly.  Thanks for reply